# How to route Wireguard within a network namespace with public internet access?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, iptables, wireguard

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for several days now, so I drew a picture (at bottom of post).

#### Context

I have a VPS with two namespaces:

- init namespace (root)
- custom namespace (my cool namespace)

As a thought experiment, I want only those connected in via Wireguard (which is hosted in `my cool namespace`) to access applications on the 10.0.0.0/16 subnet, with outbound requests outside the subnet *still* be able to hit the public internet.

For example:

- WG client 1 pings 10.0.0.1:8000 -> app loads
- WG client 1 pings 1.1.1.1 -> app loads

#### What I have working

I should preface, I'm using `wg-quick`, which I think has some inherent weirdness inside network namespaces after trying to decipher all the routing tables, but here go.

- I added iptables dnat rule to forward UDP traffic + WG port on eth0 to my veth pair. This seems to have given connecting peers access to apps hosted in the namespace. However, I cannot ping the outside world from the client (or the server).
- If I delete the `wg0` interface (wg-quick down), I can ping the outside world again.

This tells me it's definitely a routing table issue, most likely conflicting default routes between the default routing table and the wireguard routes wg-quick builds.

I'm hoping someone can streamline my overall mental model of where packets should flow, be redirected to and IPtables rules I should think about when doing this.

Since I'm learning, I'd like to keep this setup with the veth pair and not introduce any bridges, tun/taps etc.

[image]

Comment: The schematic certainly helps, but I didn't understand what should be able to communicate with what. If "my cool app" doesn't need any other access than through wireguard, then even the veth pair is not needed. Check: https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#ordinary-containerization